# How to set colors in a Visual Studio Code extension

Tags: vscode-extensions

I am setting text background colors in a VS Code add-in via `TextEditor.setDecorations()`. To do this, I use a `ThemableDecorationRenderOptions` object and set its `backgroundcolor` value to a string. (Sorry, I cannot use the theme colors.) But I do not know the possible values for `backgroundcolor` - except that values like `"red"` or `"lightgreen"` apparently work.

Is there a description of the color string format somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The colors are normal CSS colors. There are plenty of resources online which explain them.